# Redirect /old_directory/1/2/3 to /new_directory/1/2/3 in apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

How do I use `.htaccess` to redirect something like the following:

```
www.example.com/old_directory/sub1/sub2/sub3
```

to

```
www.example.com/new_directory/sub1/sub2/sub3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the top level directory:

External rewrite (i.e. if you want to change the browser URL):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^old_directory(.*) new_directory$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Internal rewrite (if you want to leave browser URL the same):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^old_directory(.*) new_directory$1 [NC,L]
```

These assume you have the rewrite module enabled in the main config:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: jerz4lunch was the above answer helpful?